# Validation Error in New Flow

Tags: visualforce, error-messages

I have created a flow in which a record update takes place.  I get the following error message and I cannot understand why I am getting it, as I am not updating this field.

**ERRORS :**

> (FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION) The Social Security
>   Number you entered is not in the correct format.  The correct format
>   is 999-99-9999 ---  for SFDC record with ID : null,
>   |FlowScreen|Client_Information

**Log :**

```
32.0 APEX_CODE,DEBUG;APEX_PROFILING,INFO;CALLOUT,INFO;DB,INFO;SYSTEM,DEBUG;VALIDATION,INFO;VISUALFORCE,INFO;WORKFLOW,INFO
16:18:16.019 (19022216)|EXECUTION_STARTED
16:18:16.019 (19056949)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|VisualForce View State
16:18:16.022 (22667079)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|VisualForce View State
16:18:16.024 (24041630)|EXECUTION_FINISHED
16:18:16.487 (487960122)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|Validation:Account:001F000000hQzFi
16:18:16.487 (487976671)|VALIDATION_RULE|03dF0000000Ryef|Account_Payable_Terms_Positive_Value
16:18:16.488 (488079546)|VALIDATION_FORMULA|AcctSeed__Account_Payable_Terms__c < 0|AcctSeed__Account_Payable_Terms__c=null
16:18:16.488 (488087035)|VALIDATION_PASS
16:18:16.488 (488089326)|VALIDATION_RULE|03dF0000000Ryeg|Discount_Days_Due_Positive_Value
16:18:16.488 (488146520)|VALIDATION_FORMULA|AcctSeed__Discount_Days_Due__c < 0|AcctSeed__Discount_Days_Due__c=null
16:18:16.488 (488152030)|VALIDATION_PASS
16:18:16.488 (488154069)|VALIDATION_RULE|03dF0000000Ryeh|Discount_Percent_Positive_Value
16:18:16.488 (488207961)|VALIDATION_FORMULA|AcctSeed__Discount_Percent__c < 0|AcctSeed__Discount_Percent__c=null
16:18:16.488 (488213446)|VALIDATION_PASS
16:18:16.488 (488215376)|VALIDATION_RULE|03dF0000000RrzT|Change_Account_Owner
16:18:16.592 (592358194)|VALIDATION_FORMULA|AND(ISCHANGED(OwnerId),
$Profile.Name <> "Senior Mediator")|OwnerId=005F0000003yopY , $Profile.Name=System Administrator
16:18:16.592 (592377999)|VALIDATION_PASS
16:18:16.592 (592382945)|VALIDATION_RULE|03dF000000113SX|Social_Security_Number_Format
16:18:16.592 (592797054)|VALIDATION_FORMULA|NOT(
OR(
LEN (Social_Security_Number__c) = 0,
REGEX( Social_Security_Number__c , "[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}")
)
)|Social_Security_Number__c=*****
16:18:16.592 (592808044)|VALIDATION_FAIL
16:18:16.592 (592821739)|VALIDATION_RULE|03dF000000113Sc|SSN_Other
16:18:16.593 (593120852)|VALIDATION_FORMULA|NOT(
OR(
LEN (SSN_Other__c) = 0,
REGEX(    SSN_Other__c, "[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}")
)
)|SSN_Other__c=*****
16:18:16.593 (593129783)|VALIDATION_PASS
16:18:16.593 (593145031)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|Validation:Account:001F000000hQzFi
16:18:16.608 (608604208)|FLOW_ELEMENT_ERROR|UPSERT --- UPSERT FAILED ---  ERRORS :  (FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION) The Social Security Number you entered is not in the correct format.  The correct format is 999-99-9999 ---  for SFDC record with ID : null, |FlowScreen|Client_Information
```

Answer (score 3):

Was the custom field validation for Social Security Number added recently?  I've had similar problems when a validation is added and there are existing records that are not in the correct format.  Any attempt to update a field on a record, even if it is a different field, will set off the validation error.